# Why am I getting this error from node.js?

Tags: json, node.js, webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to do the Udemy Modern react with redux. I cloned the repository and everything but dont get the same result as the professor in udemy. Instead I get the following. I updated to node 3.10.8 and ran:

```
npm install babel-runtime --save-dev
```

When I run npm install it works great but when I run npm start I get this error:

```
http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/
webpack result is served from /
content is served from ./
404s will fallback to /index.html
Hash: d437a155a1da4cdfeeeb
Version: webpack 1.13.3
Time: 79ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  1.51 kB       0  [emitted]  main
chunk    {0} bundle.js (main) 28 bytes [rendered]
    [0] multi main 28 bytes {0} [built] [1 error] 

ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module '../modules/web.dom.iterable'     (While processing preset: "C:\\Users\\Ryan\
\Documents\\simplestarter\\ReduxSimpleStarter\\node_modules\\babel-preset-    react\\lib\\index.js")
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous>(C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\simplestarter\ReduxSimpleStarter\node_modules\babel-preset-react\node
_modules\babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js\library\fn\get-iterator.js:1:6
3)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
 @ multi main
```

package.json contents:

```
{
  "name": "redux-simple-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple starter package for Redux with React and Babel       support",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "git@github.com:StephenGrider/ReduxSimpleStarter.git",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev- server.js",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require       ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-jquery": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "jsdom": "^8.1.0",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-redux": "^4.0.0",
    "react-router": "^2.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.0.4"
  }
 }
```

What is going on? Do I need to download a new form of babel?

Comment: Could you include the contents of your package.json?

Comment: please try `npm install babel-runtime --save-dev`, it seems that you don't install this module

Comment: did that and now I get this error:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reinstalling the local modules.  You can use this series of commands:

```
rm -rf node_modules ; npm install
```

That should reinstall everything you have configured in your package.json.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

**I got the same error and this worked for me!** 
In Section 1, Lecture 14 minute 7:17 you can see he has a semi-colon after the closing div on line 13:

[image: Code with semicolon]

The semi-colon was most likely a typo because he deletes it without saying anything at minute 7:28. At least for me, webpack was failing to compile because of the syntax error. **Once I deleted the semi-colon, everything worked!**

[image: Error from semicolon]